# Suma de Variable Proveniente de Funcion Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

La problematica es la siguiente:
Debo cargar un tipo de maquina y su respectiva maquina. El tipo de Maquina lo selecciono asi:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
 <div class="box box-info">
  <div class="box-header">
   <h4 class="box-title" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold">TIPO MAQUINA</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body pad table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
    <td>
    <?php
    $consulta = "SELECT id, nombre FROM maquinaria WHERE id_cl = '$id_us' AND estado = 'S' AND id BETWEEN 1 AND 3";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
    if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
       echo "<select name='maq' id='maq' class='form-control select2' style='width: 100%;'>";
       echo "<option value='' selected='selected'>SELECCIONE TIPO MAQUINA</option>";
       while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".utf8_encode(strtoupper($row['nombre']))."</option>";
       }
     echo '</select>';
     }else{
        echo "DEBE INGRESAR MAQUINAS";
     }
     ?>
    </td>

    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Luego selecciono la maquina a traves de jquery:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
 <div class="box box-info">
  <div class="box-header">
   <h4 class="box-title" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold">N° MAQUINA</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body pad table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
     <td>
      <select name="hidro" id="hidro" class="form-control select2" >
       <option value='' selected='selected'>SELECCIONE HIDROLAVADORA</option>
      </select>
     </td>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Cargo las maquinas a traves de esta funcion:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#hidro").change(function () {
    $("#hidro option:selected").each(function () {
    id = $(this).val();
        $.get("ajax/horometro.php", { param_id: id }, function(data){
            document.getElementById('hhi').value = data;
        });
    });
 })
});
```

En horometro.php, tengo lo siguiente:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT horometro FROM hidros WHERE id = '$_GET['param_id']' ORDER BY nombre DESC");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['horometro'];
}
```

Donde $row['horometro'] es hhi.
Luego van los inputs en donde se realiza la resta de los valores, es decir:
hhi (que viene de jquery) - hhf (que es el valor a escribir por la persona) y el resultado de esta resta, va en hht.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
 <div class="box box-primary">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
   <h3 class="box-title" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">REGISTRO HOROMETRO HIDRO</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
   <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
     <th style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center">INICIAL</th>
     <th style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center">FINAL</th>
     <th style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center">TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="hhi" id="hhi" onchange="cal()" onkeyup="cal()" class="form-control" style="width: 70px; height: 20px; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center" readonly value='' /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="hhf" id="hhf" onchange="cal()" onkeyup="cal()" class="form-control" style="height: 20px; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center" required /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="hht" id="hht" class="form-control" style="width: 70px; height: 20px; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center" readonly value="0"/></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

La forma en como pretendo sumar es:

```
function cal() {
 try {
     var a = parseInt(document.Frm.hhf.value),
         b = parseInt(document.Frm.hhi.value);
     document.Frm.hht.value = a - b;
 } catch (e) {
 }
}
```

Si fuese valores fijos, no tengo problemas, pero como cargo hhi ($row['horometro]) a traves de jquery, ya que es un select dependiente, no me funciona la suma en tiempo real.
Alguna idea de como puedo lograr eso? Agradezco cualquier ayuda u orientacion que me puedan brindar.
Saludos a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Hice un ejemplo haciendo el calculo con JQuery, los únicos cambios que realice en tu html, fue setearle un valor de entrada a "hhi" ya que ese valor lo traes de otro lado.

Te dejo el [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ph8b1rm3/1/)

Prueba escribiendo en "hhf" y el cálculo aparecera automaticamente en "hht"

**Actualización 2:**

Cree un select para simular la parte en que precargás hhi, y tuve que hacer una función para detectar el cambio en el select que setea tanto el valor, como llama a la funcion cal().
Saque esta parte del input de hhi puesto que no se añade información a mano, es un readonly:

```
 onchange="cal()" onkeyup="cal()"
```

Te dejo el [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxtgd08s/1/)

**Actualización 2:**

Entiendo tu punto, como cargas el valor cuando se realiza la consulta de jquery no podes asociar un evento que realice el calculo. Lo que deberías hacer entonces, es ejecutar el método que realiza el calculo una vez que hayas seteado el valor. De esta manera:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#hidro").change(function () {
    $("#hidro option:selected").each(function () {
    id = $(this).val();
        $.get("ajax/horometro.php", { param_id: id }, function(data){
            document.getElementById('hhi').value = data;
        cal()
        });
    });
 })
});
```

Luego de setear el elemento "hhi" forzás la función "cal()" a realizar dicho calculo. Con eso debería bastar.

Comment: muchas gracias por responder. Efectivamente funciona, siempre y cuando tenga hhi como valor fijo. Pero el problema radica es que el valor de hhi se carga a traves de un select dependiente y es un valor dinamico dependiendo que se elija en ese select, por ello la funcion que describi en la pregunta.

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta

Comment: estimado, actulice mi pregunta para su mejor entendimiento. Saludos y gracias

Comment: Actualizada mi respuesta. En caso de no ser lo que necesite, se puede llegar a abrir un chat para mejor comunicación

Answer (score 0):

La clave es usar el evento **[keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/)** para poder reflejar los cambios en el input que deseas

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) - 1
  $('#default').val(val)
  
  $('#myValue').keyup(() => {
    debugger
    const final = val - $('#myValue').val()
    $('#substract').val(final)
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="default" placeholder="Valor por defecto" disabled>
<input type="text" id="myValue" placeholder="Ingrese valor">
<input type="text" id="substract" placeholder="Valor restado" disabled>
<span id="display"></span>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas :)

Comment: estimado, actulice mi pregunta para su mejor entendimiento. Saludos y gracias